# How to use multiple class selector with OR condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 class named `Agefrom`, `Ageto`, `coverage`, `premium`. These classes are for textboxes. I want to do something whenever the text of **any** textbox changes. I wrote this jQuery but it is not working:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="Agefrom" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="Ageto" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="coverage" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="premium" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[class^=Age],.coverage,.premium').live('change', function () {
        alert('do something');
    });
});
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTN5J/2/)

Comment: possibly better find input ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `on` as `live` is deprecated and selector is case sensitive:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[class^=Age],.coverage,.premium').on('change', function () {
        alert('do something');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE UPDATED**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/Jr3Y6/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using `live` which was removed from jQuery 2.0+. Use `on` instead. Secondly, class selectors are case sensitive. Try this:

```
$('[class^=Age], .coverage, .premium').on('change', function () {
    alert('do something');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bTN5J/3/)

Also note that the `change` event on the text field will not fire until the element loses focus. If you need the event to fire as soon as there is a change to the value, use `keyup`.

A better solution entirely is to use a common class on all required elements and select that only.

Answer (score 0):

Put some *other* common class (e.g. `watchChange`) on the inputs in addition to the existing classes, and match on that, i.e.:

```
<td><input class="watchChange Agefrom" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="watchChange Ageto" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="watchChange coverage" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="watchChange premium" type="text"/></td>

$('.watchChange').on('change', document) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `,` separator for this.

live is deprecated one. You can use `on` instead of this. But your elements are not dynamic. So you can use like this

```
$('.Agefrom,.Coverage,.Premium').change(function () {
        alert('do something');
    });
```

If your elements are dynamically generated, use `on` dellegate for binding events,

```
$(document).on("change",'.Agefrom,.Coverage,.Premium',function () {
            alert('do something');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and will help you lot...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[class^=Age],.coverage,.premium').on('change', function () {
        alert('do something');
    });
});
```

Fiddle link .. http://jsfiddle.net/BL3Ft/

Answer (score 0):

Possibly better add one class to row and find all input inside? something like

```
<table>
    <tr class="rowclass">
        <td><input class="Agefrom" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="Ageto" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="coverage" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="premium" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rowclass input').on('change', function () {
        alert('do something');
    });
});
```